# Pull request merge process requiring rebase after every commit merged into master?

Tags: github, merge

I'm working in a codebase at work that requires that anyone who wants to merge a PR rebase against the last master prior to merging the pull request. To further complicate things, CI (which takes hours) has to pass before the PR can be merged, so if someone merges a commit to master while CI is running, you have to rebase (even if your PR has no conflicts with the rebase, which is the case most of the time!), rerun CI, and merge and hope no one else merges into master.

I'm not really familiar with how the merge process works with PRs, but this just seems like a ridiculously long iteration process and doesn't seem feasible if it's a codebase that receives a lot of PRs..

How typical is this?

At my previous employer, the rebase and merge is done automatically for you after CI passes. 95%+ of the time it merges cleanly. The other 5% of the time, if there's a merge conflict, it won't merge your PR, and will ask you to manually rebase against master so you can manually correct the conflicts, and then try again. I liked this process a lot better, and i have no idea why we don't currently use it. Is it substantially harder to set up on github?

How is the merge criteria set up on github?

Comment: `CI (which takes hours)`. Just curious: why?

Comment: @EricDuminil I can't answer for OP, but at my current gig we have some long-running CI, can take three or four hours. Mostly because the build server is a pentium that's old enough to vote. And we sometimes compile large projects like buildroot in CI. (and yes, I'm aware that this sucks)

Comment: @EricDuminil my guess is people added all sorts of "unit" tests that are more like e2e tests and those shouldn't be there. doesn't look like there's a priority to fix it unfortunately. also, i don't believe the CI runs every single test for every PR instead of tailoring it to the changes

Comment: In case it's not obvious: the fact that you're told to rebase you branch onto main (rather than merging main into your branch) makes no difference. People can argue as much as they like about whether it's better to rebase or to merge, but if you had to merge main into your branch instead then it wouldn't help at all with your problem :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop rebase vs merge doesn't matter in my case. i prefer rebasing because that was required at my previous employer. my current employer doesn't care about preserving a clean commit history

Comment: Yeah, personally I don't consider merge commits to be "unclean". Especially when merging branches into main, where it may be the only thing in the git log that gives me the URL I need to go and find the discussion on the PR :-). But back in the other direction, I also usually rebase onto main rather than merging from main. I do understand the "but it's a lie" argument: if you typically run the tests locally before committing, then any rebase creates a suggestion that you ran the tests at every intermediate step, when in fact you didn't. I just don't value such suggestions enough to care!

Comment: So, if you're using pre-commit hooks, or IDE plugins, or whatnot, then rebasing violates the constraint that they're trying to enforce, and so creates a "false", albeit tidier, history. But I try not to trust that past commits were necessarily ever good in the first place.

Comment: @EricDuminil we also have this problem, although not to the degree of the OP (45min~1hr in our case) because QA and the suits insist that we run E2E on every single merge, and we haven't successfully persuaded them better yet.

Comment: @JaredSmith: I suppose your "nuclear option" to end-run the policy is to separate off a testing branch. Accumulate changes there, and do the full test run prior to merging from there to main daily. The fact that this obeys the policy whilst being precisely equivalent to creating bad PRs with too much in them, suggests that (a) the policy isn't quite accounting for reality, (b) the policy creates a pressure towards bad practice: if merging a PR is expensive and difficult then people will naturally try to cram more into each one, even without the explicit "testing branch" act of defiance.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Thanks. There's a *lot* of value in E2E tests, so I guess a compromise needs to be found between testing times and % of unit tests/mocking/E2E tests. It obviously depends a lot on the scope of the software and the number of test cases, but I find anything longer than 5min too long already.

Comment: @EricDuminil: at risk of stating the obvious, it also depends what you use the main branch for. Depending on your workflows, the main branch might be CD to production, and business-critical that it must never be in a failing state. Or it might be that main is where you will create a release branch from, some months prior to actual release, with 27 stages of acceptance testing between. A broken main branch then inconveniences developers who pull bad code but doesn't otherwise do any harm at all. How protective you are of a branch surely has to be *somewhat* conditional on what it's for :-)

Comment: So anyway, if your CI automates full acceptance testing and then deploys the main branch to production then it's probably going to take more than 5 minutes for a lot of products. So the questions become "when, if ever, am I allowed to make changes but defer the full battery of acceptance tests?" and "how do we set that up?". If nobody in this team ever figured out how to set that workflow up, then that's why their tests take forever. Plus maybe they never found `make -j`.

Comment: I usually rebase, unless it makes git go crazy.  Mandates are more relevant the more junior your team is.

Answer (score 24):

The core issue here is that your CI process takes hours. Everything else is standard good practice as far as many companies/developers are concerned.

The reason to always expect a feature branch to be reasonably up to date with master (whether you do this via a rebase or a merge is irrelevant for this particular point) is to ensure that **IF** there are any conflicts, they occur in the feature branch where the other people who share the main branch with you are not affected by the time it will take you to resolve these conflicts.

You may claim that there's no reason to think that your branch would cause any conflicts, but that's a bold claim and blindly accepting it would set a dangerous precedent. Eventually, someone will claim no conflict when there's actually a conflict, and that's precisely what people want to avoid.
"I know *my* work isn't the source of the problem, so I should be able to circumvent this" is both the solution to an impractical working situation **and the cause of it**.

As to why it's a rebase; there's a tendency to prefer rebases over merges because it means your commit history isn't littered with merge messages. I agree with that point, but I also find that rebases can get ugly/complex easily and when that happens I tend to want to deviate to just doing a merge instead.
Whether you opt for a merge or a rebase is a subjective decision. Each has their benefits but they're equivalent with relation to having a PR up to date with its target branch.

As a side point, it's generally a good idea to frequently merge master into your feature branch anyway, and when you do it frequently, it shouldn't be an issue to do it one more time (just before the PR) since the amount of changes pulled in will be minimal.

> At my previous employer, the rebase and merge is done automatically for you after CI passes. 95%+ of the time it merges cleanly. The other 5% of the time, if there's a merge conflict, it won't merge your PR, and will ask you to manually rebase against master so you can manually correct the conflicts, and then try again.

The gap that this leaves is that you don't test to confirm that your merge hasn't introduced any bugs. If you run the tests first, and then merge the code, which is still an alteration to the code, how can you be sure that this didn't introduce a bug?

Your current employer's approach is safer in this regard. However, it does come at the cost of only running your tests after you merge, therefore needing to rerun your tests if you need to merge again. That's a cost/benefit analysis that I can't make based on the question you posted alone.

Comment: In the Rust community, the idea of gating the main branch/repository by an automated test process on the merged code is known as the [*Not Rocket Science Rule of Software Engineering*](https://graydon.livejournal.com/186550.html). In such a system OP's problem that some else might invalidate the main branch doesn't occur because you chuck merge-ready work into an *automated* queue that either successfully integrates (merges, tests) the work or reports an error. It may also ve possible to roll up multiple items and test them together, speeding up testing for high-confidence changes.

Comment: @amon isn't this prone to the same problems? If the "known-good revision" you started from is no longer the latest one by the time someone approved your PR and the temporary revision is tested?

Comment: @guillaume31 The trick is that no one updates the main branch except through this automated process, for example GitHub's "merge queue" feature or the Bors bot. At most one integration job will run at any time, so the merge base cannot be invalidated. But I agree with Flater that the real problem in OP's scenario is latency caused by a slow QA pipeline.

Comment: @amon Got you, I was not sure what "automated" entailed. It seems to solve some of the OP's problems indeed, similarly to the system in place at their previous company. Even with a very slow CI, at least you get the peace of mind that 95% of the time you don't have to look at a concurrently invalidated PR and the rest you'll be notified.

Comment: I was a pytorch developer previously. The process was great. IIRC and unless it's changed, CI is run before merging, and during the merge process, it does a rebase and if there's any conflicts, the author of the PR has to fix it manually. if there's no conflict, the rebase is successful, and then CI is rerun again (IIRC) and then merged after CI passes

Comment: to be fair, pytorch has over 500 paid developers and entire teams dedicated to CI-related stuff. my current codebase has < 10 devs, but the codebase is just as big (lol... because it's poorly designed)

Comment: "the rebase is successful, and then CI is rerun again" ... and then what if, again, someone else has merged to main while the tests were running. Does it repeat the process until eventually it wins that race and gets to merge?

Comment: @SteveJessop I think there's a queue that handles this, but I'm not certain. that part was a black box for me

Comment: If you’re merging master into your feature branch frequently, then it’s almost always the case that rebasing is just as easy as merging (most truly nasty conflicts are a result of being way out of sync). The practical issue with rebasing is less about resolving conflicts and more about how it makes life difficult for other people who have local copies of your branch because rewriting history means they need to nuke their local copy and rebuild it (and for reviewers, because a force push does not show what was changed relative to the previous version).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: well, that creates a kerfuffle of its own. If someone has approved a PR, and then you merge from main, then is there any more or less reason for them to have to re-review, than if you'd rebased onto main? In practice I think people tend to "muddle along" a bit here, rather than have a really solid principle. I know I do. Either way, and with or without conflicts, it's *possible* that in light of the changes coming in from the main branch, the changes in this branch are now incorrect. It's just not likely enough to spend hours of developer time on every merge over it.

Comment: But it's certainly true that you can hide significant changes in a force-push quite easily. Easily enough that it can happen by accident.

Comment: "The core issue" might be the rime of CI, it doesn't mean it's solvable. Sometimes CI just takes that long. If it takes 30 minutes just to build your program, there is no way around that.

Comment: @DanM.: Sure, but then you have to adjust your other rules based on that. I'm only pointing at a conflict, I can't tell you which is the one that's right and which is the one that's wrong. I can stop you from dipping your green paint brush in a red paint can; but I can't figure out if you are dipping the right brush in the wrong pot, or the wrong brush in the right pot.

Answer (score 3):

The specific setting in github is whether or not branches are required to be up to date with main in order to merge to main. You can turn that off. Your current build process presumably requires at least two things before merge: the branch must be up to date and the tests must pass. I don't believe it's uncommon for a repo to apply both these requirements: I work with many repos that have both, but their tests don't take hours to run.

If you change this to, "the rebase and merge is done automatically for you after CI passes", then you'll no longer be requiring that the up-to-date version of the branch passes the tests. You'll only be requiring that some version of your changes that has no conflicts with the main branch, passes the tests. Some people will consider that sufficient, and if you want to persuade your current team to change their rules then you need to convince them that it is.

Clearly it's a least a bit riskier than the stronger requirement, though. It's easy enough to come up with two changes that do not conflict in the git sense, since they don't change the same lines, and neither of which causes the tests to fail on its own, but which do cause the tests to fail once both of them are applied. The current process would catch this without merging to main: your proposed change to the process would not. But if it's the only way to get any work done then the team might accept the risk, especially if CI runs again on main after the merge. Then the risk is of a main branch clearly marked broken, not the risk of a main branch that's unknown to be broken until someone else rebases off it and tries to run the tests on their branch.

More generally the problem you're facing is that optimistic locking can cause extremely long delays with high contention. For that matter, pessimistic locking can also cause extremely long delays with high contention, but at least with the pessimistic locking you don't think you're making progress when you aren't!

Your optimistic lock looks like this:

- rebase onto main. At this point you acquire the read-only part of an imaginary reader-writer lock
- run tests (many hours)
- attempt to acquire writer lock in order to merge: fails if any write has occurred since you acquired the read-only lock. If it fails, restart the transaction from scratch.

A pessimistic lock for the same process would look like this:

- stand up in the middle of the room and loudly say, "I have a PR ready to go and I'm rebasing onto main. Nobody else merge to main until I'm done, please". Or maybe you can find some implementation other than shouting: old-timey VCS used to let you "lock" files in the repo pretty much for this reason (also to prevent conflicts even happening). But distributed version control doesn't really work like that.
- run tests (many hours)
- merge to main
- stand up un the middle of the room and loudly say, "OK, other people can merge now if they like" - they are now free to stand up, take the lock, and start their transaction.

A further consideration for your team is that regardless of the locking mechanism, there is a fundamental time constraint. Since each PR's "final" run of the tests cannot start until the previous PR's run has completed, necessarily *you cannot merge PRs faster than the tests run*. This is a real problem when the tests take many hours: how many PRs per day does your team want to be capable of merging? Put like that, probably more than two in most teams, and ideally without having to log back into work just before bed to check on your build. This argument might help persuade the team to relax the merge requirements, and/or to find ways to shorten the build process.

github does have an auto-merge feature, which you can use, to merge your PR as soon as all requirements are met. This needs to be enabled per-repo IIRC. Once enabled, on each PR that's still running the tests you get an option to "set auto-complete" in place of the usual option to merge. For that matter, you can set auto-complete while the PR is still waiting for a required review, and if that's the only requirement missing then the PR will merge as soon as it's approved. It would help you in the "happy" case where nobody else merges during your testing window. It won't help in the unhappy case where they do.

There may be another option, which is to use fast-forward only merges into the main branch. The reason this helps is that if someone is ahead of you in the queue, then instead of rebasing onto main, you can rebase your branch onto their branch. That way, once they merge to main, your branch is instantly up to date with main! And maybe you've already tested your branch by then, in which case you can instantly merge. Victory! However, this doesn't work if they do a regular merge into main, since your branch won't have their merge commit, so it won't be up to date even though it's base on an identical revision. I've never actually done this as a routine process, but I do occasionally base my feature branch off some other feature branch that I know will go in ahead of me.

I'm not *aware* of a github feature to do what you really want, which is "at the end of a successful test run, if the branch is not up to date with main but doesn't conflict, then rebase and rerun all the tests". Combined with auto-commit, this would solve your problem, although potentially it still would run the tests repeatedly for days before it can actually merge. The fact I haven't seen this feature, though, doesn't mean it doesn't exist and also doesn't mean you can't figure out a way to make your build script do that. I can't remember what the best way is to set up the permissions, because I create repos fairly rarely and they need this kind of shenanigans extremely rarely. But with the right token you basically could do "git pull; git rebase origin/main; git push" directly in your build script.

Comment: > "aware of a github feature to do what you really want" - I believe this feature is called a "merge queue". Github automatically creates a branch with a copy of the merged code for testing just before actually merging that code in.  

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-a-merge-queue

Comment: @bdsl: "just before" - or in this case, that would need to be some hours before :-)

Comment: true - but it is does seem to be doing what the OP wants, as long as github is prepared to wait the hours for the CI provider to return a result.

Comment: @bdsl also known as "merge train" (i.e. on GitLab or various automation bots like bors).